# Eclipse EL code assist on bean set by request.setAttribute() in servlet

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, el

I pass an object (of user defined class) from my servlet on request scope

```
request.setAttribute("currentStudent", cStudent);
```

and from my jsp page I access the object as following

```
First Name : ${requestScope.currentStudent.firstName}
```

everything works fine. but why I don't see object properties on the on the Eclipse code assist? I mean on normal java/jsp code as soon as I hit dot after object i see the get/set properties suggestions. why I don't see such suggestion in the case of EL?

Comment: Because Eclipse doesn't have any idea of the type of `requestScope.currentStudent`. It could be anything.

Comment: I fixed "JSTL" all over your question to say "EL". To learn what JSTL really is, carefully read the introduction of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info